# Action method does not get call

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I'm trying to use bootstrap typeahead but cannot get it to call my Action (ASP.NET MVC 4). The following is rendered in the browser :

```
<div class ="control-group">
<div class="controls">
    <input autocomplete="off" data-provide="typeahead" data-url="/GetPets" id="Pets" type="text" />
</div>
   </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('[data-provide=typeahead]').each(function () {
            var self = $(this);
            self.typeahead({
                source: function (term, process) {
                    var url = self.data('url');

                    return $.getJSON(url, { term: term }, function (data) {
                        return process(data);
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

My controller method looks like

```
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetPets(string term)
    {
        // get data from DB. Here for simplicity sake I just make data up
        var nameList = new List<string>
{
    "Dog", "Cat", "Ant", "Alligator", "Beaver", "Camel", "Clam", "Dragonfly", "Goat"
};

        var results = nameList.Where(n => n.ToLower().Contains(term.ToLower()));

        return new JsonResult()
        {
            Data = results.ToArray(),
            JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
        };
    }
```

Comment: put a break point on `GetPets` action. Make sure it gets hit. If not, you need to make sure `data-url="..."` has appropriate data.

Comment: Dmitry, it never gets to this action...

Comment: Then specify controller name: `.Controller("WhateverControllerName")`

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a url routing issue. You are using "/GetPets", but it might be needed to use "/controllerName/GetPets".  As a recommendation, try to use [HttpPost] for your actions that return Json and use $.post on client side instead.